# Memory usage per process

Tags: bash, memory

> How can one see the output of the memory usage per process in Windows using bash (Git bash) and without any additional tools installation?

I read about `top` command but there is no such thing in the default version of bash. Also, I have read about `ps` but it does not give the memory usage at all as in some examples I have seen (maybe some version has been changed).

Comment: WSL shell can only show processes running in the same container, not all the processes.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  So there is no way to check the memory in Windows via bash?

Comment: Since Linux processes run in a container (a-la Docker), they can only see processes in the same container, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Linux processes in WSL run in a container (conceptually similar to Docker), they can only see processes in the same container, nothing else.

You can see the virtual and resident size of processes in WSL by issuing the following command:

```
ps -eHww -o uid,pid,ppid,psr,vsz,rss,stime,time,cmd
```

Outputs:

```
max@supernova:~$ uname -a
Linux supernova 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #379-Microsoft Wed Mar 06 19:16:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
max@supernova:~$ ps -eHww -o uid,pid,ppid,psr,vsz,rss,stime,time,cmd
  UID   PID  PPID PSR    VSZ   RSS STIME     TIME CMD
    0     1     0   0   8324   156 23:36 00:00:00 /init
    0     3     1   0   8328   156 23:36 00:00:00   /init
 1000     4     3   0  16796  3424 23:36 00:00:00     -bash
 1000    35     4   0  17084  1716 23:57 00:00:00       ps -eHww -o uid,pid,ppid,psr,vsz,rss,stime,time,cmd
```

Comment: The problem is that I get the following output while running your command: ps: unkown operation -H. My `ps` supports only: --all; -e, --everyone  show processes of all users
 -f, --full      show process uids, ppids
 -h, --help      output usage information and exit
 -l, --long      show process uids, ppids, pgids, winpids
 -p, --process   show information for specified PID
 -s, --summary   show process summary
 -u, --user      list processes owned by UID
 -V, --version   output version information and exit
 -W, --windows   show windows as well as cygwin processes

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan I installed Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows Store.